# Getting a human readable device type from a IOBluetoothDevice

Tags: objective-c

How can I go about getting a human readable device type from a `IOBluetoothDevice` object? I see there is a `classOfDevice` property but it returns an int. I need a way to tell if the device is a phone or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I found there is no built in function for this. The header file

BluetoothAssignedNumbers.h

listed all the codes and will let you figure things out. You'll have to build your own ID -> string function.

I checked out the `remoteNameRequest` and I may be doing something wrong but it did not return a human readable device class name for me, ie: `Phone`, `Smartphone`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to use the `remoteNameRequest:` method.  See the docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/devicedrivers/Reference/IOBluetooth/IOBluetoothDevice_h/Classes/IOBluetoothDevice/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/IOBluetoothDevice/remoteNameRequest%3a).